# formated hard drive with ext4 permission denied when creating or moving files

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems

I formated a hard drive with ext4 using `sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sda`, I also tried using the KDE partition manager with the same result:

A "lost+found" folder appears when I mount and open the drive and when I want to create a directory using `mkdir test`, I get the answer `Permission denied`.

Does anyone know how I can make the hard drive work again?

Comment: ehm, after answering I noticed that  you created the file system on `/dev/sda`. I hope that's a type, otherwise: you should create filesystems in the partition (`/dev/sda1`) and not on the complete disk (`/dev/sda`).

Comment: It really depends on your needs. Partitioning is not exactly crucial.

Comment: I tried both. When I used the partition manager it made a partition table like it was before (I hope)

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely a permission problem. If you do

```
sudo mkdir test
sudo chown your_user_id test
```

you should be able to create your own stuff under `test`.

If you `chown` and/or `chmod` the top of the file system when it is mounted, it should be accessible for the right users.

One word of caution: do not make everything world-writable. If you have multiple users, give them their own directory (like you did with `test`)

Comment: The `uid` mount options applies only to a few filesystem types, namely those non-linux ones.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked for me and now I can use it to copy files. And how can I make the disk useable again for any user? Also to create files in the root dir of the disk?

Comment: @TomYan You're right. Forgot that this was ext4.